# extract string from text with batch

Tags: batch-file, automation

I am working on an automation project: to complete the puzzle I left with this thing.

I have a file (com.txt):

```
AUX = \DosDevices\1
1 = \Device\Serial0
10 = \Device\VCP0
7 = \Device\Silabser0
8 = \Device\Silabser1
```

I need to read this file using batch and create 3 variables:
look for "Silabser0" and insert "7" to a var
look for "Silabser1" and insert "8" to a var
and look for "VCP0" and insert "10" to a var
(those numbers are changing from file to file but the Silabser0/1 and VCP0 are permanent )

output for npocmaka:

```
C:\Users\Test\Desktop>set file_loc=c:\COMports.txt

C:\Users\Test\Desktop>for /F "usebackq tokens=1 delims== " %a in ("c:\COMports.t
xt") do (for /F "tokens=2 delims=\" %x in ("%b") do set %x=%a )

C:\Users\Test\Desktop>(for /F "tokens=2 delims=\" %x in ("%b") do set %x=AUX )

C:\Users\Test\Desktop>(for /F "tokens=2 delims=\" %x in ("%b") do set %x=1 )

C:\Users\Test\Desktop>(for /F "tokens=2 delims=\" %x in ("%b") do set %x=10 )

C:\Users\Test\Desktop>(for /F "tokens=2 delims=\" %x in ("%b") do set %x=7 )

C:\Users\Test\Desktop>(for /F "tokens=2 delims=\" %x in ("%b") do set %x=8 )

C:\Users\Test\Desktop>echo
ECHO is on.

C:\Users\Test\Desktop>echo
ECHO is on.

C:\Users\Test\Desktop>echo
ECHO is on.
```

Answer (score 1):

not tested (assuming that paths always has two separators - `\`)

```
@echo off

set file_loc=vals.txt

for /f "usebackq tokens=1* delims== " %%a in ("%file_loc%") do (
   for /f "tokens=2 delims=\" %%x in ("%%b") do set %%x=%%a
)

echo %Serial0%
echo %VCP0%
echo %Silabser0%
echo %Silabser1%
```

Comment: your assumption is correct. but it doesnt work. ill add the output to the end of the question

Comment: @Mike - script has been fixed and tested.Check my edit.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort! that looks much better but it looks like there is a problem with the vars, like they didnt get its values. see output in the end of my question

Comment: @Mike - looks like you've pasted the code directly to the command prompt?

Comment: No, i used a batch file

Comment: i think that we should use dynamic variables somehow

Comment: @Mike there's something strange in your output - why there's a space before the x here - `("c:\COMports.t xt")`?

Comment: i don't know where the space came from in this example but i don't see it in my batch or the CMD window.This file is ANSI format, should it be unicode? it doesn't work in unicode.

Answer (score 0):

iv'e edited the file to look like:

```
AUX\DosDevices\1
1\Device\Serial0
10\Device\VCP0
7\Device\Silabser0
8\Device\Silabser1
```

and then used:

```
set file_loc=c:\COMports.txt

for /f "tokens=1,3 delims=\" %%a in (%file_loc%) do set %%b=%%a
```